# routing torrent traffic through a different network interface

Tags: networking, routing

I am on a mac and I have wifi and data network card interfaces configured to access the internet on my machine.

I want to route all torrent traffic over the wifi interface and browsing traffic over the data network card interface.

I can add a route and route all of the traffic using

```
sudo  route change -net 0.0.0.0 -gateway ip.addr
```

How do I force only the torrent traffic to fall on one specific interface?

Comment: I don't think you can do this. Routing decisions are done simply by looking up the destination address in the routing table, and are independent of the application.

Comment: You need to clear up what you want a bit more.  All "internet traffic" would include "browsing traffic" if you are talking about browsing web sites with a web browser.

Comment: i meant torrent traffic .. i edited the post. Sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

you need a  proxy server or a port forwarding rule in your firewall.. and set the port in the torrent client.

Problem is that i have no clue how to do this on mac.. sorry

Comment: [link](https://www.paloaltonetworks.com/documentation/71/pan-os/newfeaturesguide/wildfire-features/enable-the-firewall-to-forward-mac-os-x-files) ..how bout that;P